# MapkIt coordinates being changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

Trying to plot things on a mapkit map but my lat and lng being passed in is being changed?

I pass in a lat of 39.34343 and it gets changed to 7.33121668909306e-304?

What am I doing wrong?

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.latitude = *(thing.lat);
coordinate.longitude = *(thing.lng);
```

If I "po coordinate.latitude" after the above code, I get 7.33121668909306e-304

Comment: You'll need to show what `thing` is, and how it's `lng` is set up.

Answer (score 1):

`latitude` isn't an object, it's a double (typed to be a `CLLocationDegrees`). You can print an `int` or `double` like this:

```
// Code
int i = 3;
double doub = 2.3;

// In the Debugger
(lldb) print (int) i
(int) $1 = 3
(lldb) print (double) doub
(double) $2 = 2.3
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how I can print it out, but why is the coordinate.latitude being changed?  My plots are 39.3434 and -75.14, but again they are being changed when set in the code above. That lat is 7.33121668909306e-304 and lng is 7.33121668909306e-304   , which puts it out in the middle the pacific ocean, not philly where it should be.

Comment: (lldb) print (double) coordinate.latitude printed out 7.33121668909306e-304

Comment: The issue isn't printing in terminal, it has something to do with me assigning a double (pulled out of coredata) coordinate.latitude.